# Existing MVC Web Application with .NET standard library, IDE errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-standard-2.0

I converted one of our commonly used libraries to .NET standard 2.0 for mobile application use as well as use in existing applications.

Using this library in an existing Mvc application (4.7.1 Framework) it builds and runs successfully but the Visual Studio IDE reports a list of build errors for the controller classes around not being able to find elements of the library. The using clause of this library is also greyed out in the controller classes.

Is there an easy way to resolve this?

Comment: Are you using embedded resources from library? Like: Views or javascript file located in to external compiled library?

Comment: Nope, no embedded resources in the .NET standard library

Comment: Have you tried Cleaning/Rebuilding the project?

Comment: Yep tried cleaning/rebuilding and re-referencing library to no avail. The IDE doesn't like the library in the MVC projects, whereas it is fine in other projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading from MVC 5.2.3 to 5.2.6 has solved.